# Getting the current locale in django

Tags: django, localization, internationalization, locale

It is easy to get the current language (e.g. en) anywhere in a django app: django.utils.translation.get_lanaguage()

But how do I get the current locale (e.g. en_US or en_GB)?

Answer (score 4):

Did you try `to_locale()`?

```
from django.utils.translation import to_locale, get_language
to_locale(get_language())
```

Comment: to_locale(get_language()) still only outputs 'en' if language is 'en'.

Comment: The docs for to_locale say: Turns a language name (en-us) into a locale name (en_US). If 'to_lower' is True, the last component is lower-cased (en_us)...... It therefore expects a language name which is a language + country. My problem is that a locale contains both the language and country, so cannot be extracted from just the language.

Answer (score 2):

The distinction between `language` and `locale` (in Django, at least) is just a matter of formatting. Both `en` and `en-us` are languages, and if `en-us` is the currently selected language then that will be returned by `get_language()`.

So your problem seems to be that Django is not setting the current language the way you expect. There's a [long list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference) of techniques Django uses to try and figure out the language to use, so I suggest working your way down that to see why the language isn't what you expect.

For example:

> If a base language is available but the sublanguage specified is not, Django uses the base language. For example, if a user specifies `de-at` (Austrian German) but Django only has `de` available, Django uses `de`.

Answer (score 2):

Django's `django.utils.translation.to_locale()` expects a "language name" like `en-us` and will convert that to a "locale name" like `en_US`.

Source code: [https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/translation/**init**.py#L271-L284](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/translation/__init__.py#L271-L284)

It basically just does some string manipulation.

If your "language name" is just a simple language code like `en`, it will return just `en`. If you want to convert `en` to a locale like `en_US.UTF8`, you will have to write your own `to_locale()` function. You'll have to determine what locale you want for the language code `en`. Example:

```
LANG_TO_LOCALE = {
    'en': 'en_US.UTF8',
    'nl': 'nl_NL.UTF8',
    'es': 'es_ES.UTF8'
}

def lang_to_locale(language_code):
    return LANG_TO_LOCALE.get(language_code)
```

Depending on your taste you might for example want to get the locale `en_GB.UTF8` instead of `en_US.UTF8` for the language code `en`.

This then can be used to set the locale in Python:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, lang_to_locale('nl'))
```

And then you can get a month name in the desired language:

```
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%B'))  # Prints month name in Dutch
```

To make this work you need to have the appropriate locale packages installed on your system. On Ubuntu you can do this with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`.

Answer (score 2):

In the relevant (virtual) environment:

```
python
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getlocale()
```

e.g. ('en_GB', 'UTF-8')